# EC2: How to tell if disk volume is instance store or EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a number of volumes (same size) attached to a Windows EC2 instance in Amazon AWS.

One of them is told to be an instance store, the rest are EBS.

How do I tell which one is the instance store? They all look the same in Device Manager - "XENSRC PVDISK SCSI Disk Device"

PS. testing the speed did not help, one of the drives IS slightly faster than the others but how I can be sure it's an instance store?

Comment: The instance metadata service may be able to provide what you are looking for: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: @datasage Thanks for pointing me to that direction, but this metadata has no use for a Windows Instance (I don't know which block device is which disk in Windows)

Comment: @datasage figured it out, see tedder42's comment to his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got done doing this with unix servers in Ansible last week! [Here are the block devices that are instance stores on Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html#parts-of-a-block-device-mapping). If you want to see which ones are actually available, look for entries in the block-device-mapping. I'm showing the following with `curl` and a Linux host because it's easier to illustrate:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/2014-02-25/meta-data/block-device-mapping/
ami
ephemeral0
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/2014-02-25/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0
sdb
```

In this case, sdb (or xvdb) is an instance-store.

Here are some further links:

- [How to add swap to and Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350985/how-to-add-swap-to-and-amazon-ec2-instance-running-ubuntu-12-04-lts)
- https://gist.github.com/joemiller/6049831

Comment: Ok, this gives me "ephemaral0" which is "xvdca", thanks for that. But how the f**k do i tell which windows drive is "xvdca"?????!?!?!? (this drives me nuts)

Comment: [here you go](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html). A bit of voodoo- note you need to follow the "device name mapping" link to complete the circle (e.g., get back to xvdca).